# Build a production custom docker image of grafana from it github

Tags: docker, grafana

I need make some changes on the code of grafana an them compile it.

I have downloaded the github repo, made the changes and rum

```
docker build -t custom-grafana -f Dockerfile .
```

As you can see many site over internet.

The problem is that compile in this way make a build from v7.5.0-dev version of grafana, and I need use the latest version...
I cant find de way to compile a custom grafana code using the latest version of gfrafana code.

I need help...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloned the grafana repository from GitHub than you must checkout the branch/tag that you want to compile.

The latest version at the moment is 7.5.6, you can just check it out before building the docker container.

```sh
git checkout v7.5.6
```

Comment: thanks for answer, Martteo. This give me an error. After make git checkout, I executed docker build and in a point of the build, I received this error:
`> [js-builder  5/11] RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile --no-progress:
#26 1.046 yarn install v1.22.5
#26 2.042 [1/5] Validating package.json...
#26 2.112 [2/5] Resolving packages...
#26 8.369 [3/5] Fetching packages...
#26 8.776 error Couldn't find the binary git
#26 8.776 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.`

Comment: I had the same problem. From what I could gather it is an issue with the Dockerfile: in the `js-builder` stage the use git (for downloading node packages) but the image does not have git installed. You should add `RUN apk --no-cache add git` before line 8. They have it fixed in the main branch (you can compere the two Dokefiles) but not in the latest tag unfortunately.

Comment: I wrote this line before line 8, but still give an error 
` error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/source-map/-/source-map-0.5.7.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-source-map-0.5.7-8a039d2d1021d22d1ea14c80d8ea468ba2ef3fcc-integrity/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-generator.js'"
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn install --pure-lockfile --no-progress]: exit code: 1`
Y try to use de dockerfile from main branch, but didnt work..... is a little bit frustrating

Comment: maybe try to remove the yarn.lock file before building docker image. Agree with you, I remember ti being quite frustrating getting the docker image to build.

Comment: no way... I had removed the yarn.lock and exec yarn install to rebuild the file, but docker still fail...